# Giving a row number to mysql data based on date

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, row-number

I have been trying to add a row number for my data i.e. each row would have a number based on my ordering, if I list them based on date, the one which is the oldest date would get row number 1 and so on regardless of their actual id stored in the database.

I have wrote this query but if I insert a column with a date older than the previous ones, it doesn't get the row number 1 as I want it to.

Here is my query :

```
SET @row_number=0; SELECT @row_number := @row_number +1 AS 'row number', physiotherapy_evaluation_form_id AS 'id',
CONCAT( student_first_name, ' ', student_second_name, ' ', student_third_name, ' ', student_last_name ) AS 'student name',  
therapist_first_name, date FROM physiotherapy_evaluation_form,student, therapist WHERE therapist_id = therapist_id_fk 
AND student_id_fk  =student_id AND  student_id = 2 AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-10' ORDER BY date ASC
```

I'm using C# and windows forms.

What I'm getting is : 
[image: unwanted output]

I want to be in this format

```
row     date
1       2015-01-10
2       2015-02-02
3       2015-03-05
```

Comment: What _does_ it get? Can you provide two _short_ samples of data (original and after-additional-insert) which demonstrate the behaviour you're experiencing?

Comment: @Ceisc I have added images to demonstrate what I want, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by making the query related to my order by seperate and taking the result of it and adding to the first query of the select row_number

here is the corrected code in case someone wanted to get an idea:  `SET @row_number=0; SELECT @row_number := @row_number +1 AS 'row number', table1.* FROM (SELECT physiotherapy_evaluation_form_id AS 'id',
CONCAT( student_first_name, ' ', student_second_name, ' ', student_third_name, ' ', student_last_name ) AS 'student name',

therapist_first_name, date FROM physiotherapy_evaluation_form,student, therapist WHERE therapist_id = therapist_id_fk 
AND student_id_fk  =student_id AND  student_id = 2 AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-10' ORDER BY date ASC ) AS table1`